# With custom CtkEntry how do we place entry text at the top inside of the widget?

Tags: python

Running this on pc my, this code justifies left but I cannot figure out how to get the text from the middle to the top. I have tried anchor, but that just moves the widget not the text within it.
Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
`import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("800x600")

def nextBtn():
    print("test")

frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill="both", expand=True)

label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="DISSECTOR", font=("Roboto", 20))
label.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

msgEntry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=500, height=200, corner_radius=5, placeholder_text="put message to dissect here", justify="left")
msgEntry.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

nextButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="NEXT", command=nextBtn)
nextButton.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

root.mainloop()`
```